# Does android browser caching automatically?

Tags: android, caching, android-webview, browser-cache

Hi I have a question about the caching of an android webapp which specifically runs about webview. Before I made a cache manifest the cache of the app was 9mb and after I loaded the cache manifest file up the app cache was 5mb. In chrome on PC its faster and all become loaded from cache but I dont know how its on android browsers. It looks that android caches automatically and a cache manifest isnt needed. I load jquery from a external source and have php and javascript files. Does they become automatically cached?

EDIT:

I think android and chrome cache automatically I checked it in the network console and after the first load it loads all files from cache, without php files.